# Strange QRegExp to Identify non-ASCII Characters

Tags: c++, ascii, qt4.8

In a legacy codebase, developed with Qt4.8, C++, for an ASCII-based application, I saw the following lines

```
    const QRegExp lBadCharsRegExp("[^\\x{001F}-\\x{007E}]");

    // if we find a match, our string contains some bad chars
    bool lMatches = xStr.contains(lBadCharsRegExp);
```

The character class in the QRegExp is weird. It looks like the author was aiming for a range of hex characters, but the curly braces are unneeded. Moreover, if I pass in a string containing every printable character, it rejects *just* '~'.
If I instead do

```
const QRegExp lBadCharsRegExp("[^\\x001F-\\x007E]");
```

the '~' is also accepted.
Can someone explain

- the odd syntax in the first QRegExp
- why it excludes *just* '~'

Comment: I think you have some assumptions about character encoding in here. How many characters do your string with "printable characters"  contain? and do you generate it exactly the same in both cases ?

Comment: @SamuelÅslund, if you are referring to the application, I imagine the strings are not overly long. The intention was to allow the user to display arbitrary expressions in a DSL. But as mentioned, the application is ASCII-based, so the code is (I believe) trying to prevent entry of non-ASCII Unicode characters. My test string has all the printable characters on my keyboard, including '~'.